# Looping through rows, if 3 cells meet the criteria then highlight cells, if not then hide row

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to set up a spreadsheet that, when you click a button, looks the cells in column 4, 7, and 8 in each row and if the criteria of the three cells is correct, the entire row highlights. If the criteria is not correct I want to hide the incorrect rows.

I seem to be getting stuck where the code selects the row to highlight. I had tried using ActiveCell.EntireRow.Interior.Color but it only ever either highlights everything in the range or highlights the row of whatever cell was selected before clicking the button.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim rng As Range: Set rng = Application.Range("A5:I54")
Dim cell As Range
Dim row As Range
Dim i As Integer

       For i = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
                If rng.Cells(RowIndex:=i, ColumnIndex:=4).Text = "Yes" And rng.Cells(RowIndex:=i, ColumnIndex:=7).Text = "Yes" And rng.Cells(RowIndex:=i, ColumnIndex:=8).Text = "No" Then
                rng.EntireRow.Interior.Color = vbYellow
                ElseIf rng.Interior.ColorIndex = vbWhite Then rng.EntireRow.Hidden = True
                End If
        Next

End Sub
```

How can I get the code to recognise the criteria of the row and highlight it correctly?

Comment: Your problem is that you are setting the column index for the standard column numbers, but you are working within a specified rng, so the first column of the range would be 1 not 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your problem, this code will do it:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

For i = 5 To 54
    If Cells(i, 4) = "Yes" And Cells(i, 7) = "Yes" And Cells(i, 8) = "No" Then
        Range(Cells(i, 4), Cells(i, 9)).Interior.Color = vbYellow
    ElseIf Cells(i, 4).Interior.Color = vbWhite Then
        Cells(i, 4).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: You can get rid of the `ElseIf` all you need is `Else: Cells(i,1).EntireRow.Hidden = True`

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked perfectly. I can't quite wrap my head around why your code works without declaring the ranges. Can you explain this to me?

Comment: @GMalc you are probably right, from the post text it does look like all non yellow rows would be white. But since he had the check for white in his code, I thought it would be better to keep it.

Comment: @Moonshine54; the range is set by using the `5 To 54` for the rows, and columns `4, 7, 8, and 9`. He was able to use the standard column numbers because he is not working within a set range. Also, if you expect to add more rows to your sheet, then you will need to add a last row variable.

Comment: @Moonshine54 you shouldn't declare "cell" and "row" like you did, they are already objects in VBA. In my code, since I didn't specify workbook and worksheet, Excel assumes Cells(i, 4) to be ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 4).

Comment: This was wrong `rng.Interior.ColorIndex = vbWhite`.

Comment: @Moonshine54 - your approach was better in terms of defining your range as Lucas's code (which I did upvote) will only work for the range A5:A54.